# Changing activity background on click event

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I want my activity to switch between two drawable backgrounds when a simple button is clicked.
Here's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="start"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Now I want the botton to switch background1 with background2 (both png in res/drawable).
I've read about setBackground, setBackgroundDrawable and setBackgroundResource, which one should I use and how?

Answer (score 0):

.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) is deprecated, use setBackground(Drawable)

Use this for API 17>:

```
layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_image));
```

and API 16 < you use:

```
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't be offended if I say so, but the internet's forums cannot replace learning the basics of programming/using an API.

Comment: I'm not offended! You are right... I'm new to Android and I know that asking for help for everything is not the way to go.  I just couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There you go;

```
public void switch(boolean isFirst)
{
   int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
   if(isFirst)
   {

      if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.background1);
      }
      else {
          getWindow().setBackground(R.drawable.background1);
      }
   }
   else
   {

      if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.background2);
      }
      else {
          getWindow().setBackground(R.drawable.background2);
      }
   }
}
```